# How to convert a given string to palindrome?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, optimization, palindrome

I had an interview question which is:

> "Convert a given string to an palindrome, provided the output
>   (palindrome string) should contain the substring of the given string"

So I did this way, given `root` as input I will find the reverse of that string and append it to the given input. So I get string :

```
roottoor
```

which is an palindrome and also contains i/p (`root`) is present in the o/p.

Given the solution, the interviwer said, its not optimal solution can you give an optimal one?

I couldn't able to find any apart from this.

Any other solutions?

He said its need to be done in Java.

Comment: Very quick optimization would be to only add the first n-1 letters, as the last letter will be the center then, i.e.:
`root` -> `rootoor`
`stack` -> `stackcast`

This is only very minor though and does not change the time-complexity of the solution, so you might need more than this ;)

Comment: What is meant by "the substring"? In what way was the proposed solution "not optimal" - in terms of length of the output?

Comment: I think that `rootoor` is shorter than `roottoor`

Comment: Can you provide the code you used?

Comment: Extending the comment of @MrHug, try to detect if the input string already contains a palindrome at its end, it will be at least the last character (as MrHug suggested). Then copy the remaining characters backwards from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given string `s`, find the longest substring `s1` at the end of `s` that is already a palindrome. Then just put the reverse of `s\s1` at the end.

For example, for the input string `"lambada"`, `"ada"` is a palindrome, so you just add the reverse of `"lamb"` and the result is `"lambadabmal"`.

**EDIT:** Considering maartinus' answer, you should also check the opposite direction and choose the one that results in a shorter palindrome:

For a given string `s`, find the longest substring `s1` at the beginning of `s` that is already a palindrome. Then just insert the reverse of `s\s1` at the beginning.

For example, for the input string `"arafat"`, `"ara"` is a palindrome, so you just insert the reverse of `"fat"` at the beginning and the result is `"tafarafat"`.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer obviously misses to look at the beginning. Example

```
racecars -> racecarsracecar // when only the end is considered

racecars -> sracecars       // when the start is considered
```

Just look at both ends and return the better result.

Comment: You are right, I (incorrectly) only considered appending something at the end of the given string. Given the original question, the other possibility (inserting something at the beginning of the string) must also be considered.